# TimeOut dinámico Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure

Estoy desarrollando un *pipeline* en *ADF* y quisiera que el *timeout* de cada una de las actividades fuese dinámico y que este valor se pueda ingresar como parámetro al disparar el *pipeline*:

Parámetro: 
[image: Parámetros]

Timeout:
[image: Actividad Lookup]

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En ese caso debes hacerlo utilizando la API REST.

> PUT
>   https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/12345678-1234-1234-1234-12345678abc/resourceGroups/exampleResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/exampleFactoryName/pipelines/examplePipeline?api-version=2018-06-01

Para crear/actualizar  el pipeline puedes enviar un request con el conjunto de actividades y en cada actividad puedes establecer su politica de ejecución. En la política de ejecución puedes establecer el timeout.

```
 "activities": [
            {
              "type": "Copy",
              ...,
              "inputs": [
                {
                 ...,
                  "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
              ],
              "outputs": [
                {
                  ...
                }
              ],
              "policy" :{
                       ...}
              "name": "ExampleCopyActivity"
            }
          ]
```

[image: Policy Details]

Puedes checar toda la documentacion, aquí:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/createorupdate

Y es importante validar si el esfuerzo requerido vale la pena, porque el request es nua cosa, pero hay que revisar el tema de autenticación y de como se acopla esto a lo que ya tienes, pues puede requerir algo de desarrollo adicional.

Comment: Implementado!!!!! mil gracias